# Django TemplateSyntaxError at /school/

Tags: django

Hi I'm working on a student database app and I made more features and stumble on this error.Everything thing seem clear
I understood what this error mean because I encountered before but with this app . I don't know what went wrong.

```
 TemplateSyntaxError at /school/
 Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'cat' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
 Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError 
 Exception Value: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'cat' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
 In template /home/tafe/mysite/school/templates/index.html, error at line 3

 Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'cat' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
 1 {% if students %}

 2 <ul>        

 3  {% for student in students %}  
 4  <li><a href="{% url school:cat poll.id %}">{{student.First_name}}</li>
```

My views.py

```
 from mysite.school.models import student
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404

 def index(request):     
       students = student.objects.all()
   return render_to_response('index.html',{'students':students})

 def cat(request,poll_id):
   students = get_object_or_404(student,pk =poll_id)
       return render_to_response('student.html',{'students':student})
```

My index.html

```
 {% if students %}
  <ul>        

{% for student in students %}  
<li><a href="{% url myapp:cat poll.id %}">{{student.First_name}}</li>    
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

My student.html

```
 {% if students %}
 <ul>
   {% for student in students %}  
 <li>{{student.First_name}}</li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

My URLconf

```
 from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns,include , url 
 from django.contrib import admin
 from mysite.school.views import index,cat

 admin.autodiscover()

 urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^$',index),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$',cat,name='cat'),
 )
```

Comment: It's just muck up app ,to see what I can bulit .Okay sure that if your not busy

Comment: okay  , i sent it . thank you cathy

Comment: welcome and I hope you will learn it now?

Comment: Yep , I alway try to discover the mistake and thank you @catherine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main urlconf for school has **$**, this is the reason why you get the error

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^school/',include('school.urls',namespace='school')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

As I go further, these are the errors I encountered:

1. your index has no httpresponse
2. you did not defined get_object_404
3. if your model is student don't use variable same with student, make it students or anything
4. when your using get_object_404 or render only one value. You must not use forloop on it. Just call student.first_name or student.id

Comment: oh sorry about the other errors . It was cause when I was copying one line at a time into my usb folder . I must have forgot those lines at the top.

Comment: .Do you know my cat function. I was using a get_object_404 with a forloop inside it and it didn't work so I changed it too student.objects.all() and it works :D

Comment: it will not be working on the forloop because you are only calling one data. Forloop only works if there are many data to filter